# Get the Parameters of a Method from a Generic Class - TypeScript

Tags: typescript, generics, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I have a generic class with two methods, one of which calls the other. As both take the same parameters,  I'm trying to use the [Parameters Utility Type](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#parameterstype) to duplicate the parameters of one into the other. However, I can't figure out how to pass along the generic when accessing the class's methods:

```ts
class Thing<T> {
    _a: T;

    constructor(a: T) {
        this._a = a;
    }

    original(anotherA: T, b: string) {
        // do something...
    }

    unOriginal(...params: Parameters<typeof Thing.prototype.original>) {
        return this.original(...params);
    }
}
```

As you can see in the `unOriginal` method, I don't pass the generic `T` anywhere. As a result, `params` evaluates to `[anotherA: any, b: string]`. Instead, I want it to evaluate to `[anotherA: T, b: string]`, but I can't figure out how to pass the `T` generic when referencing `Thing.prototype.original`. For example, something like `Parameters<typeof Thing<T>.prototype.original>`.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use `Thing<T>["original"]` rather than `typeof Thing.prototype.original`

```
class Thing<T> {
    _a: T;

    constructor(a: T) {
        this._a = a;
    }

    original(anotherA: T, b: string) {
        // do something...
    }

    unOriginal(...params: Parameters<Thing<T>["original"]>) {
        return this.original(...params);
    }
}
```

Comment: Definitely solved the problem! But do you have any info on why this works and what the difference is? Thanks!

Comment: The problem is that you can't pass generics to types created using `typeof`. Also, the generic is on the class itself, so you need to pass it on that level rather than on the `unOriginal` function level if you get what I mean